# How to execute spring-boot:run from terminal for Remote Debugging

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, remote-debugging

I'm trying to run the `./mvnw spring-boot:run` command so that I can do the **remote debugging** for that process.

I tried

```
 ./mvnw exec:exec 
           -Dexec.executable="java" 
           -Dexec.args="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
           spring-boot:run
```

I get the log **`Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005`**

But I get the error and maven process **exits**

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ sample-project ---
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:764)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:711)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:289)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:122)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:50)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### How can I send execute `spring-boot:run` from terminal so that I can use it for Remote Debugging?

> Note I'm using Maven Wrapper for executing maven life cycle process, hence, I don't have access to **`mvnDebug`**

Comment: Your script is running two separate Maven goals. I don't know about spring-boot but as far as the java command is concerned (the one called in `exec:exec`), it always needs the main class (or an executable Jar file). You should probably modify the question to clarify that it involves Spring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are already using `spring-boot:run` in your project to run the application, then simply follow the instructions in the plugin's documentation for debugging the server....

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run-example-debug

```
mvn spring-boot:run \
    -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug \
          -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

If you've got the `spring-boot` plugin in your project, then just use the **`spring-boot.run.jvmArguments`** property

If you're not already using the spring-boot plugin, then you shouldn't be passing spring-boot:run to Java.  Java will know nothing about that.  To run the jar from the command line, you use "java -jar "... so that will need to be reflected in the exec:exec command.  You need to, additionally, look at the exec plugin to see how to pass it jvm arguments (Which is what is needed to set up debugging).  Just using the spring-boot plugin is a bit easier.

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked and plus point for information about maven plugin `jvmArguments`